# Трассировщик диаграмм БД

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите существует ли нормальный инструмент построения диаграмм по существующей БД, который создаст диаграмму с минимумом пересечений (по типу трассировки печатных плат)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парочка самых популярных. Первый свободно распространяемый.

[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

[SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog)

upd.: между таблицами должны быть внешние ключи; иначе магии не получится.